# How do I integrate R code with Quarto without writing all my code in qml files, but in R scripts instead?

Tags: r, quarto

I'm learning R and Quarto and wish to do the bulk of my analysis in R scripts. Every resource on Quarto I've found so far teaches how to use it by embedding all the code in the qml files.

My questions are:

1. Are there any resources for integrating Quarto with a separate R project?
2. Do you have any tips on how to do this effectively?
3. I would prefer to be selective about which code snippets actually make it into the final document, so I would like to be able to get the full functionality in Quarto without having to bring all of my R code into the document itself. Is this possible, or have I got the paradigm all wrong?

If the answer to this question is "read the bloody manual", I would appreciate direction as to which part. I have been looking for answers for a while.

Comment: Applying `source()` is probably your best bet, on well-named R scripts